# Laravel Migrations breaks when migrating new tables into the database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, database-migration

Iam trying to migrate Laravel table migrations into the database but every time I make new tables and run `php artisan migrate` Laravel complains that user table exists and even the newly added migrations are not created in the database, and when I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` I lose my data is there a better way to do this without losing my data in the already existing tables. Below is the table i want to add.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up() {

        Schema::create('drivers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('contact')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('nin')->nullable();
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('verified')->nullable()->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        });
    
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('drivers');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it perhaps saying that the Class `CreateUsersTable` already exists?

I can see that the class name is CreateUsersTable, but you should probably rename to CreateDriversTable

Comment: Nice catch @Brett.